# The iOS build of Unity requires In-App purchasing, although my game don't use IAP

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I have a game in Unity which uses the Unity Analytics service. I have made sure that my Unity build don't have In-App purchases in the Unity Editor.  I have never implemented In-App Purchases in my game and I have set the IAP option to off:
[image: Unity_IAP_off]

But my Xcode project generated by Unity shows the error, "The 'In-App Purchase' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program." 
[image: Xcode require IAP]

What did I miss?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?, I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the "In-App Purchase" Capability in XCode:
Edit:
1. Select Project
2. Select Capability 
3. Turn In-App Purchases off

[image: Turn off the "In-App Purchase" Capability in XCode]

Comment: please give more detail (with screenshot if possible) because I am not familiar with XCode.

Comment: @HahaTTpro see above.